# Add string from textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a textbox1 which input by user and textbox2 for user to input numbers which can automatically generate textbox1 value into multiple string such as example below:

```
Txtbox1 = ABC12345
Txtbox2 = 3
```

Result will be

```
ABC12345-1
ABC12345-2
ABC12345-3
```

Comment: only get value from txtbox and try to use an button to triggle when txtbox2 is input

Comment: this forum is not to discuss logic, rather its to discuss syntax or other such problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use button and apply click event.

```js
function getString() {
  var finalString = [];
  var t = $("#textbox1").val()
  var n = $("#textbox2").val();
  if (t.toString().trim() != "") {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      finalString.push(t + "-" + (i + 1))
    }
  }
  console.log(finalString)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Text : <input type="text" id="textbox1"><br><br> Number : <input type="text" id="textbox2">

<button type="button" onClick="getString()" id="textbox1">Get</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using something like this below, but kinda hard to make it 100% as you want, since you haven't shown any HTML.

```js
$("[id^=Txbox]").keyup(function() {
  var empty = $("[id^=Txbox]").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
  }).length == 0;
  if (empty) {
    var str = $("#Txbox1").val();
    var number = $("#Txbox2").val();
    var arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      arr.push(str + "-" + i)
    }

    console.log(arr)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Txbox1" />
<input id="Txbox2" type="number" />
```